# DragLeave doesn't get called

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

in my VB.Net application I am try to drag and drop a custom control. It should be dropable onto another instance of the same class. So here is the code I use:

```
Private Sub HandleMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    Me.DoDragDrop(Me, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub

Private Sub HandleDragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    e.Effect = If(checkDropData(e), DragDropEffects.Copy, DragDropEffects.None)
End Sub

Private Sub HandleDragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    addControl(e.Data.GetData(GetType(MyControl)))
End Sub

Private Sub HandleDragLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragLeave
    Console.WriteLine("HandleDragLeave: " & sender.ToString)
End Sub
```

I am able to drop the control but while dragging the `DragLeave` event never gets called. Did I miss something?

Comment: Haven't checked hence a comment rather than an answer but from memory you need to handle the DragLeave event on the target.

Comment: @OSKM I think that's true, but the target and the source are instances of the same class, so the target should handle the event or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very bad... I used the wrong signature but the was nothing which told me I was wrong.

I found the solution [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1541578). I used `DragEventArgs` instead of `EventArgs` as type of `e`. After changing the type it works like expected.